# spring-cassandra UDT data insert

Tags: java, annotations, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

Can someone help me to find out how to insert Cassandra UDT data using `Spring` POJO class?

I created one POJO class to map Cassandra's Table and Created one another class for Cassandra UDT, but when i inserted main POJO class that map Cassandra's table than it's not recognized another POJO class( map Cassandra's UDT). I have also written anotation on every class and on every class object .

Here is My one POJO class :-

```
package com.bdbizviz.smb.model.entity;

import org.springframework.cassandra.core.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;

import com.bdbizviz.smb.cassandra.udt.CoverPhoto;
import com.bdbizviz.smb.cassandra.udt.Location;
import com.bdbizviz.smb.cassandra.udt.MailingAddress;
import com.bdbizviz.smb.cassandra.udt.Reference;
import com.bdbizviz.smb.cassandra.udt.RestaurantServices;
import com.bdbizviz.smb.cassandra.udt.RestaurantSpecial;
import com.bdbizviz.smb.cassandra.udt.VoipInfo;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Frozen;


@Table("source")
public class Sources {


Integer likes;
Integer followers;
Integer rating;
String last_processedtime;
String filter_str;
String filter_type;
String category;

@PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal=0,type=PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
String admin;

@PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal=1,type=PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
String name;

@PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal=2,type=PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
String source;

@PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal=3,type=PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
Integer id;

@PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal=4,type=PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
String type;

Integer delete_flag;
Integer evaluated;

@Frozen
Reference fb_reference_id_name ;

@Frozen
MailingAddress fb_mailingaddress;

@Frozen
CoverPhoto fb_coverphoto ;

@Frozen
VoipInfo fb_voipinfo;

@Frozen
RestaurantServices fb_restaurantservice;

@Frozen
RestaurantSpecial fb_restaurantspecialties;

@Frozen
Location fb_location;

/* Setter and Getter */
}
```

Another POJO class :-

```
package com.bdbizviz.smb.cassandra.udt;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Persistent;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Field;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.UDT;

@UDT(name = "reference" ,keyspace="smb")
public class Reference {

@Field(name="id")
String id ;

@Field(name="name")
String name;

/* Setter and Getter */
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Spring-data-Cassandra 1.3.2.RELEASE support UDT annotations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753799/does-spring-data-cassandra-1-3-2-release-support-udt-annotations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cassandra Driver is not even support UDT feature. You have to use Cassandra's custom driver for this feature.

Here is the maven dependency for Cassandra Driver

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-dse</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: how should i use it with spring-data-cassandra? I tried with @UDT but failed.

Comment: can you share which dependency you are using for cassandra ?

Comment: latest jar of Spring data cassandra supports UDT. see below for more explanation.

Comment: Duplicate of [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753799/does-spring-data-cassandra-1-3-2-release-support-udt-annotations/41996636#41996636

Answer (score 0):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

is needed